# www-data as the expeditor of a mail sent with contact 7, ssmtp being the server

Tags: ssmtp

On my Debian Raspberry, i have installed ssmtp. When I send an email, using Wordpress' contact 7 form, the email appears as sent by www-data, the owner of the directory where wordpress is installed.
How can I change this ? it is so ugly !

Here is my ssmtp.conf:

```
root=sebastien@xxx.com
mailhub=smtp.orange.fr:25
rewriteDomain=xxx.com
hostname=raspberrypi
FromLineOverride=NO
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using FastCGI based apache/PHP server which would send the mail as the mail account configured for the user hosting the WordPress site. You can also configure WordPress to send SMTP though a different server.

WordPress may already be trying to send mail using the correct "From" address, but I do see that your config has `FromLineOverride=NO` as described in this StackOverflow question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675703/ssmtp-rewritting-from-field-in-emails

Comment: Thanks Kristopher 
Finally, I have uninstalled ssmtp, installed others, reinstalled ssmtp ! and it works fine.
I think the pb was more or less the fact I was using Orange with a port 25, and now I am using Gmail with a port 587, secured.